# FormData and checkboxes

Tags: javascript

Currently when creating a `FormData` object, a checked checkbox is added with a value of "on", and an unchecked checkbox is not passed at all.

Do I have to hack in some hidden inputs to properly set checkboxes, or is there some customization I can do with FormData, or pre processing?

I would prefer a checked checkbox to be 1 and an unchecked to be 0. I can already do this myself (ie ugly hack), but I don't see any native way with FormData.

```js
form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(form);
  for (const [name,value] of data) {
    console.log(name, ":", value)
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="form">
     <input name="normal" type="text" value='example' />
     <input id="inpt" name="on" type="checkbox" />
     <label for="inpt">on</label>
     <br /><button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can always call `set` on the `FormData` object manually. Otherwise it behaves exactly like HTML forms do.

Comment: instead of adding hidden inputs, process on server. If checkbox value is 'on' convert to 1 and if checkbox value is blank or null convert to 0. Checkbox value is drive by browser, so you can't change it. You can add the extra properties.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Currently when creating a FormData object, a checked checkbox is added with a value of "on", and an unchecked checkbox is not passed at all.

`on` is only used if the checkbox is missing a `value` attribute

> Do I have to hack in some hidden inputs to properly set checkboxes

No. That *is* properly handling checkboxes. It is how they have worked in forms since the form element was added to HTML.

Test for the presence or absence of the checkbox in the code that handles it.

Comment: Well the code that handles it is `var fd = new FormData(myForm);`

Comment: I mean the server side code that handles that HTTP request you probably create using XMLHttpRequest and `fd`.

Comment: It's an embedded system and I cannot alter the server code. I will just use hidden inputs.

Comment: @BarryBones41: Why don't you just do `fd.set('myCheckbox', fd.has('myCheckbox') ? '1' : '0');` ?

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
var checkbox = $("#myForm").find("input[type=checkbox]");
$.each(checkbox, function(key, val) {
    formData.append($(val).attr('name'), this.is(':checked'))
});
```

It always adds the field to `FormData` with either a value of `true` when checked, or `false` when unchecked.

Comment: $(val).is(':checked') instead of this.is(':checked')

Comment: nice dude, but would it be better not to append if not checked.

Comment: Thx alot, `$(val).attr('name'), $(this).is(':checked')` this is worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I took a slightly different approach from the existing answers. I created my form data variable the standard jQuery way inside my form submit event handler:

```
var form = $(this).get(0);
var formData = new FormData(form);
```

Based on [Quentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487482), saying that it is only set to 'on' when the `value` attribute is not available, I just added a document event on change to all checkboxes to set the value when the user checks or unchecks the input.

```
$(document).on("change", "input[type='checkbox']", function () {
    var value = $(this).prop('checked');
    $(this).val(value);
});
```

When my form data object is created in the above way, all checked checkboxes now have the value of 'true' rather than 'on'.

This worked quite nicely for my purposes and seems to me to be a pretty simple fix. Interestingly, having `value='false'` doesn't do anything as the input is just ignored and not added to the form data object if it is not checked. But obviously that still works.