# Symfony3: How to update boolean to false using PATCH method

Tags: symfony

I have a big entity and a big form. When updating my entity, I only render parts of my form, through ajax calls. On client side, I'm using Jquery and **html5 FormData**, so I can also send files within my form. To make sure the fields that are not rendered won't be set to null in the process, I'm using **PATCH method**.

So when a field is **not present** in the request, it's **left as is** by Symfony.

But when the field I update is a boolean (rendered a a checkbox) that was set to true and I want to set it to false, it's not passed in the request, so my **update is ignored**.

Is there an easy way to force unchecked checkboxes to appear in the request?

**EDIT**
I found a way to force unchecked checkboxes to appear in the request, thanks to Felix Kling's comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487360/formdata-and-checkboxes) :

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    formData.set($(this).attr('name'), formData.has($(this).attr('id')) ? '1' : '0');
});
```

Unfortunately, **this didn't solve my problem**, because of Symfony's behaviour:
- When using *PUT*, if the boolean field appears in the request, it's set to true, **regardless of its value** (even if it's "0" or "false").
- When using *PATCH* method, the fields not appearing in the request are ignored.

Could that be solved with DataTransformer? (I've never used it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here goes a working solution, that **could be improved**.

To force unchecked checkboxes to appear in the request, thanks to Felix Kling's comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487360/formdata-and-checkboxes), I've added this js before my ajax request :

```
$("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function() {
    formData.set($(this).attr('name'), formData.has($(this).attr('id')) ? '1' : '0');
});
```

Then, on the Symfony side, I had to override the BooleanToStringTransformer behaviour, that returns `true` for whatever string and `false` only for null value. Making a change in the last line, we now return **false** if the value doesn't match the value defined for **true** ("1" by default). So if the value returned by the form is "0", we get **false**, as expected.

```
public function reverseTransform($value)
{
    if (null === $value) {
        return false;
    }

    if (!is_string($value)) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException('Expected a string.');
    }

    return ($this->trueValue === $value); // initially: "return true;" 
}
```

Following [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html), I made my own DataTransformer, as well as a custom *AjaxCheckboxType*

Unfortunately, it seems that Symfony uses **both** DataTransformers (mine and the original one), one after the other, so it didn't work. In the docs they extend `TextType` not `CheckboxType`, that must explain the problems I encountered.

I ended up copying and pasting the whole `CheckboxType class` in my own AjaxCheckboxType, only changing the DataTransformer's call in order to use mine.

A much nicer solution would be to totally override the DataTransformer, but I don't know how.

Comment: You can reset data transformers with $builder->resetViewTransformers(). Then add your own DataTransformer.

Comment: @Falc Excellent! Thats exactly what I needed!

Comment: Good solution! I implemented this within a `PatchableCheckboxTypeExtension` extending `CheckboxType` to make this behavior easily configurable via an `accept_null_on_patch` form field option. If it is set to true, it removes all ViewTransformers and adds a `PatchableCheckboxBooleanToStringTransformer` instead.

Comment: And now I see, that (at least in currect Symfony 3.3) the CheckboxType also accepts null as a valid input value. See my detailed answer on this.

Answer (score 5):

You are absolutely right, Symfony will ignore it if method is PATCH because of [this line in Request Handler](https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/2b018b299266510961e23467ac6d8460faa4524b/Extension/HttpFoundation/HttpFoundationRequestHandler.php#L116):

```
$form->submit($data, 'PATCH' !== $method);
```

Now, I would generally suggest that you use a `PUT` request if that is an option, but if it isn't then second argument to `FormInterface::submit($submittedData, $clearMissing = true)` is what you're after.

The "proper" way would probably be to make your own implementation of [`Symfony\Component\Form\RequestHandlerInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/RequestHandlerInterface.html) which would force `$clearMissing` to be `true`.

Other, way is a lot easier but might not work for all use-cases: use `$form->submit()` directly.

If you have the following code:

```
$form->handleRequest($request);
```

You can do:

```
$form->submit($request->get($form->getName()), true);
```

You can also omit second parameter since `true` is the default value

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can't revert PATCH's behaviour for all my fields. Since I'm rendering only a small part of the form, I *have* to leave absent fields untouched on update... except for the checkboxes that I rendered. I think I need to render the checkboxes in a way that they will appear in the submit request even when they are *not checked*.

Answer (score 1):

## Symfony handles this out of the box, just prepare your PATCH-payload properly :)

The Symfony CheckboxType, at least in the current version 3.3 (seems like since 2.3, see update below), accepts an input value of `null`, interpreted as "not checked" (as you can see in lines 3-5 of the snippet in [Roubi's really helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35215074/2564552)).

So in your client-side AJAX-PATCH-controller you set the value of of your (dirty) unchecked checkbox-field in your `application/merge-patch+json` payload to `null` and everything is fine. No form extensions overwriting CheckboxType's behavior needed at all.

Problem is: I think, you cannot set values of HTTP-POST-payload to `null`, so this only works with JSON (or other compatible) payload within the request body.

## A simple demo

To demonstrate this, you can use this simplified test controller:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/test/patch.json", name="test_patch")
 * @Method({"PATCH"})
 */
public function patchAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder(['checkbox' => true, 'dummyfield' => 'presetvalue'], ['csrf_protection' => false])
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl($request->get('_route')))
        ->setMethod('PATCH')
        ->add('checkbox', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CheckboxType::class)
        ->add('dummyfield', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType::class)
        ->getForm()
    ;
    $form->submit(json_decode($request->getContent(), true), false);

    return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($form->getData());
}
```

For PATCH-requests with `Content-Type: application/merge-patch+json` or in this case also any valid JSON-payload, the following will happen:

Submitting the checkbox with `null` value

```js
{"checkbox": null}
```

will overwrite the checkbox to false:

```js
{"checkbox": false, "dummyfield": "presetvalue"}
```

and submitting the checkbox with its original value

```json
{"checkbox": "1"}
```

will set the checkbox to true (was also true before)

```json
{"checkbox": true, "dummyfield": "presetvalue"}
```

and no submitted value for the checkbox

```json
{"dummyfield": "requestvalue"}
```

will leave the checkbox in its initial true-state and only overwrites the dummyfield:

```json
{"checkbox": true, "dummyfield": "requestvalue"}
```

This is how a PATCH request should work, no extra hidden inputs needed. Just prepare your JSON-payload on the client-side properly and you are fine.

## OK, but what about the expanded ChoiceType/EntityType?

For expanded ChoiceType (or child types of it like EntityType), which renders checkboxes or radiobuttons and expects a simple list of the checked checkboxes/radiobuttons values within the submitted payload, this simple solution doesn't work. I implemented a form extension, adding an event listener for PRE_SUBMIT on those fields, setting the non submitted checkboxes/radiobuttons to null. This event listener must be called after the closure-listener of CheckboxType, transferring the simple list `["1", "3"]` to a hash with checkbox-values as keys and values. A priority of `-1` workes for me. So `["1" => "1", "3" => "3"]` coming out of the closure gets `["1" => "1", "2" => null, "3" => "3"]` after my listener. The listener of my `PatchableChoiceTypeExtension` looks basically like this:

```php
$builder->addEventListener(
    \Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
    function (\Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent $event) {
        if ('PATCH' === $event->getForm()->getRoot()->getConfig()->getMethod()
            && $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOption('expanded', false)
        ) {
            $data = $event->getData();
            foreach ($event->getForm()->all() as $type) {
                if (!array_key_exists($type->getName(), $data)) {
                    $data[$type->getName()] = null;
                }
            }
            ksort($data);
            $event->setData($data);
        }
    }, -1
);
```

Update: have a look at this comment within the submit-method in /Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php (it is there since Symfony 2.3):

```
// Treat false as NULL to support binding false to checkboxes.
// Don't convert NULL to a string here in order to determine later
// whether an empty value has been submitted or whether no value has
// been submitted at all. This is important for processing checkboxes
// and radio buttons with empty values.
```

Update 2017-09-12: Radiogroups must be handled the same way as Checkboxgroups, so my listener handles both. Selects and multi selects work correctly out of the box.