# FOSRestBundle - PATCH not working as should

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I want to update entity with 'PATCH' method (update only those fields which have been submitted).

```
  /* Edit an existing Content entity.
  *
  * @Rest\Patch(
  *     "/{content}.{_format}",
  *     requirements={"content" = "\d+"},
  *     defaults = { "_format" = "json" }
  * )
  *
  * @Rest\View(serializerGroups={"user""admin"})
  * @param Content $content
  * @return View
  * @throws \NotFoundHttpException*
  *
  * @ApiDoc(
  *  resource="/api/content/",
  *  description="Updates content data",
  *
  *  input="ContentBundle\Form\ContentType",
  *
  *  output={
  *   "class"="EntriesBundle\Entity\Content",
  *   "parsers"={"Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\Parser\JmsMetadataParser"},
  *   "groups"={"user","admin"}
  *  }
  * )
  */
 public function editAction(Request $request, Content $content)
 {
     if (!$content) {
         throw $this-createNotFoundException();
     }

     $editForm = $this-createForm('ContentBundle\Form\ContentType', $content);
     $editForm-submit($request-request-get($editForm-getName()));

     $view = View::create()
         -setSerializationContext(SerializationContext::create()-setGroups(['user']));

     if ($editForm-isSubmitted() && $editForm-isValid()) {
         $em = $this-getDoctrine()-getManager();
         $em-persist($content);
         $em-flush();

         $view
             -setStatusCode(Codes::HTTP_OK)
             -setTemplate("ContentBundle:content:show.html.twig")
             -setTemplateVar('contents')
             -setData($content);

     } else {
         $view
             -setStatusCode(Codes::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST)
             -setTemplateVar('error')
             -setData($editForm)
             -setTemplateData(['message' = $editForm-getErrors(true)])
             -setTemplate('ContentBundle:content:show.html.twig');
     }

     return $this-get('fos_rest.view_handler')-handle($view);
 }
```

Form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('eng', CheckboxType::class, [
            'required' => false
        ]);
}
```

I have entity with 'eng' set to `TRUE`.
If I run query to update only `title` field, `eng` changes to `false`. and `description` to null. Any ideas why?

Comment: When having a PATCH request, you will want to pass `false` as the second argument to `Form::submit()` so that missing properties will not be cleared.

Comment: If you happen to update your boolean to false using PATCH, it might not work. See this question for more details and solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187867/symfony3-how-to-update-boolean-to-false-using-patch-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it to works.

Remember folks that if you want to use `PATCH` method you need to use `TextType` instead of `ChoiceType` in your form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
            ->add('eng', TextType::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that, because you are not using the request body converter and you are defining your routes manually, the method of your form need to be set.

Try something like this:

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(
   'ContentBundle\Form\ContentType', 
   $content, 
   ['method' => 'PATCH']
);
```