# Don't undestand why expanded ChoiceType value is not submitted correctly

Tags: php, symfony

While editing an existing "entity", the value of my ChoiceType expanded is not submit correctly when I submit the form (`handleRequest()`): The $request contains the correct values, but the $form->getData() don't.
In other word, if a default value is already set on this field, I can't update it.

I'm on *Symfony 3.4.15*, on a client-side application that communicates with an API. **I don't have any entities on this side**, I'm just getting the resources on the API and work on arrays.

I have no problem with form validation. To be sure that it worked well, I tried to define a value that does not exist in the option "choice" and there I have an error.

I've already find a way to understand this problem by setting the "data" option to false. This fixes the problem when sending the values, but I don't more recover the original value when initializing the form.

Here my form:

```php
//OrdersItemsType class

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options
{
    $builder
        ->add('type', ChoiceType::class, [
            'label' => 'label.type',
            'choices' => [
                'label.total' => 'total',
                'label.simple_partial' => 'simple_partial',
                'label.complex_partial' => 'complex_partial'
            ],
            'expanded' => true,
            'multiple' => false,
            'empty_data' => 'total' //comment or uncomment this line don't change anything
        ])
    ;
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'form_name';
}
```

Here the lines when I submit the form:

```php
dump($customFormData);

$form = $this->createForm(OrdersItemsType::class, $customFormData, [
    'method' => 'PATCH'
]);

if ($request->isMethod('PATCH') && $form->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
    dump($request->request->all());
    dump($form->getData());
    exit;
}
```

Here the dump of $customFormData:

```
array:2 [
  "form_name" => [
    "type" => "simple_partial"
  ]
]
```

Here the dump of $request->request->all():

```
array:2 [
  "_method" => "PATCH"
  "form_name" => [
    "_token" => "my_valid_token"
    "type" => "complex_partial"
  ]
]
```

And here the dump of $form->getData():

```
array:2 [
  "form_name" => [
    "type" => "simple_partial"
  ]
]
```

I expect to have the `$customFormData` values (the actual values of my entity) when I initialize the form to prefill it, and to get the `$request` values when I submit the form (just as a form is supposed to work and that works perfectly well on the other fields), but I actually can't update this expanded ChoicesType.

> Edit : After more test, I can say that:
>
> - If the `type` is initially `"total"`, I can't change it at all.
> - If the `type` is initially `"simple_partial"`, I can change it to `"total"` but not to `"complex_partial"`.
> - If the `type` is initially `"complex_partial"`, I can change it to 
>     `"total"` and `"simple_partial"`.

_

> Edit2: After further tests I see that the order of choices in the ChoiceType influences the value I can modify : In concrete terms, I can not change the type if the value I send is below the current value in the list of choices.

Comment: I wonder how you checked this. Is it possible that your form rendering is screwing things up? Have you checked if this also happens if you change it via API?

Comment: @Jakumi I currently don't send anything to the API, but all work on it side.
But with more tests I see that the order of choices in the ChoiceType influences the value I can modify...

Comment: can you investigate with a dom inspector, if the values found in the specific form field are actually related to the values in the choices array? and if they are not: can you provide the templates that generate your form. of course you can post your template anyway. ;o)

Comment: @Jakumi The value on the DOM are what the `$request` variable contains. But here is an overview of the DOM anyway: https://ibb.co/jWs1Nyj

Comment: yeah, that looks like it's supposed to look. The only thing, that I found weird in your code: the normal way to do request handling with the form: `$form->handleRequest($request);` then afterwards to check: `if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { /*...*/ }`. you have this somewhat inlined, and I'm not quite certain, if this actually makes a difference. OH ... what I also see, your `$customFormData` should just be `['type' => 'simple_partial']`, so without the `form_name` wrapping ... I believe. might explain why *some* things don't work. doesn't explain the behaviour though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, for lack of time, I gave up the `ChoiceType ['expanded' => true]` (radio buttons) for a simple `ChoiceType`(select list) and that solves the issue.

I have no explanation for the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the PATCH and that expanded fields have subfields that are not correctly updated on PATCH. This leads to two active subfields (the new one and the old one) and then the first of those two fields wins. I came across that yesterday and it drove me crazy. And now I realized that I already had a solution for that with a wordy answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056461/2564552