# Javascript: How to get ID of input in FormData?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form of checkboxes. On submit, I get the FormData object and get access to the name and value of the selected checkboxes. However, I also need the unique ID identifier in order to properly POST the data to my backend. Looking through SO and the Mozilla docs, I have not found a way to get access to the ID property in addition to the name and value.

How do I get access to the id property on a selected input? Thanks for the help!

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="customerResponse" value="Twitter" id="221"/>
    <span>Twitter</span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="customerResponse" value="IG" id="222"/>
    <span>IG</span>
  </label
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="customerResponse" value="FB" id="223"/>
    <span>FB</span>
  </label
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
function logSubmit(form) {

    let data = new FormData(form);
    let testarr = []
    for (const [name, value] of data) {
      if (value !="") testarr.push([{responseName: name},{customerResponse: value}])
    }

    console.log(testarr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `element.id` like this:

```
var idStr = element.id; // Get the id
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Where would I be calling `id` on? `let data = new FormData(form);` returns an object of key, value pairs. I tried this implementation as well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/entries: `for(var pair of formData.entries()) {} ` but `pair` is an array of key value pairs as well

Comment: This question may be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33487482/8801599).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use FormData to get the ID, but you can use below code:

```
$(form).find('input:checked').each((e, value) => {
                console.log(value.id);
                //Here you can use value.id 
            });
```